# Incomplete Visibility Product

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, 3d-analyst, viewshed, visibility

I am running ArcMap 10.2 and have been trying to complete a fairly large viewshed analysis and have chosen to use the [visibility tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000zr000000) in order to be able to produce an optional above-ground-level (AGL) layer which will be the focus of further analysis.

The visibility is from a layer consisting of 2 points and the raster is a DSM. I have run several repetitions of this tool (both 3D Analyst & Spatial Analyst) and every time the process completes successfully producing a viable viewshed, but there is never any AGL to be found. There are no errors accompanying the completion of the tool either.

Why would this be? How do I get the tool to produce an AGL? I have tried using only one viewer point as opposed to two without any difference in the outcome.

Comment: To progress this I think we will need you to include a more detailed description of the input data, tools and parameter values used.